# Index title too low with scrbook + imakeidx + original

Tags: spacing, koma-script, indexing

I’m using the document class `scrbook` and the package `imakeidx` together with the option `original` to create an index.
But I noticed that the index title is lower than all the other occuring titles (table of contents, chapters, bibliography, etc.).

[image: index title is too low]

The same happens with `scrartcl` but not with `scrreprt`.
It also doesn’t happen without the option `original`.

> Is this behavior intended?
>   If it is not, how can it be fixed?

I suspect that it is not intended since `scrreprt` behaves differently than `scrbook` and `scrartcl`.

```
\documentclass[a6paper, 10pt, oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
Lorem\index{lorem} ipsum\index{ipsum}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: I checked using Lamport's original index package, and the index looked like `imakeidx` with the `original` option. In section 3.24, page 150 in KOMA-script manual, the author write: ‘_Using a package that redefines commands or environments for the index KOMA-Script’s ability to influence the index may disappear. This applies, for example, when using the index package, but not when using the splitidx package (see [Koh14])._’  It seems that imakeidx interferes with KOMA-script when you use the `original` option. Probably, you cannot blame KOMA-script, but you may send messages to the authors.

Comment: I assume `original` reset the index page layout to the original LaTeX version, not to KOMA-scripts version. Whey it does not happen in `scrreprt` may be because the original layout of LaTeX report class is different than the book-class, and co-incidentially lines up with scrreprt. I have not analysed the source. If you use the makeidx-package in scrreprt, the headings in the index chapter is in line with other chapters, it is not moved down. I have not analysed the source, so this is just an assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's plainly an issue in `scrbook`; whether it depends on `\twocolumn` it's a matter of discussion. If I try

```latex
\documentclass[a6paper, 10pt, oneside]{scrbook}

%\usepackage[original]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
Lorem\index{lorem} ipsum\index{ipsum}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

[image]

which is *exactly* the same as you get with

```latex
\documentclass[a6paper, 10pt, oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[original]{imakeidx}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
Lorem\index{lorem} ipsum\index{ipsum}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

You can somewhat fix it by using `multicol`.

```latex
\documentclass[a6paper, 10pt, oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[original]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{etoolbox,multicol}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\idx@heading}{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \@chaptertolistsfalse
  \idx@@heading{\indexname}%
  \ifidx@leveldown
    \addsecmark{\indexname}%
  \else
    \@mkdouble{\MakeMarkcase{\indexname}}%
  \fi
}
\apptocmd{\theindex}{\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}\begin{multicols*}{2}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\endtheindex}{\end{multicols*}}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter*{Test chapter}
Lorem\index{lorem} ipsum\index{ipsum}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

KOMA-Script uses something like `\twocolumn[<indexheading>]`, but `\twocolumn` adds additional vertical space before a heading in the optional argument. So it is an issue of the LaTeX command `twocolumn`. If you look carefully you will see that it also happens with `scrreprt`.

I have asked Markus. He suggests to use package `imakeidx` (without option `original`) or another package which allows to load package `multicolumn` and to activate the `multicols` environment *after* the index heading.